# при добавлении слэша (/) в конец url сайта, переносит на главную

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, mvc, оптимизация-сайтов

Докончил делать проект с использование MVC и замети что при подставлении / в конец url любой страницы сразуже идет редирект на главную страницу. 
Причину так и не смог найти. в .htaccess у меня есть

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Тоесть у меня у всего сайта автоматом должны убираться / в конце
Но если написать например site.ru/article то все будет работать а если site.ru/article/ то переносит на главную страницу. 
В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать лишнюю группу захвата:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

И поаккуратнее с 301 редиректом, возможно браузер помнит старый редирект "не туда".

---

Также можно захватывать url на этапе rewritecond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: убрал но все также не работает, не знаете как можно сделать так чтобы браузер забыл про старый 301 редирект ?

Comment: Очистка кеша должна помочь, по идее.

Comment: Второй вариант тоже не работает?

Comment: Есть ли другие правила rewrite в вашем .htaccess?

Comment: После того как удолил то что вы написали и почистил кэш браузера  все заработало и больше нету редиректа, спасибо !

Comment: 301 редирект имеет смысл использовать только, когда вы уверены, что он корректен. Пользователей кеш почистить не заставишь. Временный редирект - 302